# c# String Splitting based on '//'

Tags: c#, string

```
string str ="Planning process and execution//Rules for ramp up and ramp down//Transport//Packaging//Logistics quality//Special cost//Communication";
```

I have to split this string based on `"//"`.

Currently I am getting this error:

> Too many characters in literal.

Comment: You want to get help in fixing your code without posting code, right?

Comment: Kevin, thats not really gonna work.... his data contains the ``//``. Sinatr has a good point. Please share your code, we're here to help, we are not going to write programs for you.

Comment: @Sinatr  There is nothing to post with Code, I gave my requirement clearly. It is easily under stable.

Comment: Sinatr and Rob Quist for comments like yours people like Jon Skeet and others from StackOverflow want to do this place a friendly place.You could just ask for a code sample without other remarks. It's simpler..

Comment: @Sinatr what is the issue here, I just ask for help.

Comment: @CalinVlasin, the puzzle with error message without code what causes it is unsolvable, even by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string str = "Planning process and execution//Rules for ramp up and ramp down//Transport//Packaging//Logistics quality//Special cost//Communication";
string[] Sep= {"//"};
var result = str.Split(Sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```
string text = "Planning process and execution//Rules for ramp up and ramp down//Transport//Packaging//Logistics quality//Special cost//Communication";

string[] words = text.Split(new string[] { @"//" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

foreach (string s in words)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

For reference: [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx)

Comment: Thanks... Working with this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This will do

```
    var list = str .Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, this will split on both `/` and `//`:

```
string[] arr = Regex.Split(str, @"/+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result= str.Split(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar);
```